# Integrate the given equation

Tags: integration

Here is the equation that has to be integrated plus my answer:
$$
\int \frac{x}{2x^2-1}dx=\frac12\cdot\frac23\ln{|1-2x|} +C
$$
The correct answer:
$$\frac14 \ln{|1-2x|} + C$$

How it come? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that your correct stated answer is correct? Anyway, try a u-sub on the denominator and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $2x^2-1=t$

we get $2(2x)dx=dt$

Substitute and get the desired answer.

Comment: sorry but I'm missing a step how do you derive 2(2x)

Comment: @cash differentiation of $x^2$ w.r.t $x$ gives $2x$. The other 2 is the coefficient of $x^2$ taken as it is. Anything else?

Comment: what happens to the x in the numerator then?

Comment: The equation after differentiation $4xdx=dt$ is equivalent to $xdx=\frac{dt}{4}$. Substitute it back in your equation to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** replace $2x^2-1$ with $u$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try a substitution of $u = 2x^2-1$, then $du = 4x \, dx$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\dfrac{x}{2x^2-1}dx=\int\dfrac{d(2x^2-1)}{4(2x^2-1)}=\dfrac{1}{4}\ln|2x^2-1|+C$$

Comment: how did you get d(2x^2 -1) ?

Comment: @cash $$\dfrac{d(2x^2-1)}{4}=\dfrac{2d(x^2)}{4}=\dfrac{4xdx}{4}=xdx$$